# Can't update existing record in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need to update existing recode in the database.I'm using mysql.

this my model class

```
class SuSurey(models.Model):
    #id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    su_name = models.CharField(db_column='su_Name', max_length=30) # Field name made lowercase.
    description = models.CharField(db_column='Description', max_length=500, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    duration = models.IntegerField(db_column='Duration') # Field name made lowercase.
    audience = models.CharField(db_column='Audience', max_length=20, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    start_date = models.CharField(db_column='Start_date', max_length=50, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    end_date = models.CharField(db_column='End_date', max_length=50, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    create_date = models.CharField(db_column='Create_date', max_length=50, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    update_date = models.CharField(db_column='Update_date', max_length=50, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    create_by = models.IntegerField(db_column='Create_by', blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    update_by = models.IntegerField(db_column='Update_by', blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.su_name
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'su_surey'
```

i didn't use any forms in my web application. In my view.py i have this

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            date=request.POST.get('dates','').split('-')
            survey_data=SuSurey.objects.get(id=survey_id)
            survey_data.su_name=request.POST.get('Name','')
            survey_data.description=request.POST.get('Description','')
            survey_data.duration=request.POST.get('Duration','')
            survey_data.audience=request.POST.get('Audience','')
            survey_data.start_date=date[0]
            survey_data.end_date=date[1]
            survey_data.update_date=datetime.datetime.today()
            survey_data.update_by=request.session['user_login_data']['id']
            try:
                survey_data.full_clean()
                survey_data.save(update_fields=['su_name','description','duration','audience','start_date','end_date','update_date','update_by'])

                messages={'success':'Successfuly data added'}
                url = reverse('addQuestionSurveys', kwargs={'survey_id': survey_id })
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url)


            except ValidationError as e:
                messages={'error':e.messages}
                return render(request, 'pages/forms/newSurvey.html',{'dept_data': dept_data,'messages': messages},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

when i add data Django did update the recode that is find by survey_id recode. it will add new recode to database.how can i fix this problem ? need a quick help thank you.

Comment: why you are using `managed = False` ?. if it is true, Adding an automatic primary key field to the model if you don't declare it. To avoid confusion for later code readers, it's recommended to specify all the columns from the database table you are modeling when using unmanaged models.

Comment: Model.objects.get() should never create a new record

Comment: `managed = False` is created when i run inspect-db. i changed it also same result :(